# How to populate a Google Chart from an HTML table?

Tags: php, jquery, charts

I have a question, is it possible to populate a Google Chart from an HTML table?

I have successfully initialized the Google Chart in Wordpress like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Language', 'Speakers (in millions)'],
      ['German',  5.85],
      ['French',  1.66],
      ['Italian', 0.316],
      ['Romansh', 0.0791]
    ]);

  var options = {
    legend: 'none',
    pieSliceText: 'label',
    title: 'Swiss Language Use (100 degree rotation)',
    pieStartAngle: 100,
  };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Table is filled dynamically unfortunately

```
  <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Kg</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td>[85-dynamic value]</td>
   <td>[86-dynamic value]</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>`
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Sure, generate your array structure in php and use `echo json_encode($arr);` to get it to javascript.

Comment: Im not really good at php, actualy im working only with wp plugins.
Ive been able to show a table/view with this piece of code
  '<?php echo FrmProDisplaysController::get_shortcode(array('id' => 234)); ?>'

But i dont know how to bind it to array a then use json_encode($arr) . Little example would be great. Thanks

Comment: Can you add how you are getting the data in php? I assume that's where it is coming from as the question is tagged php.

Comment: just like i wrote above. It is formidable plugin called formidable pro   
echo FrmProDisplaysController::get_shortcode(array('id' => 234));


http://formidablepro.com/knowledgebase/insert-a-custom-display/